# Ordering of sub and superscripts

Tags: support, mathjax

I would like to write this expression:

[image]

However, I am only able to produce:

$$\nabla_cR_{abc}^e$$

this is with:

```
\nabla_cR_{abc}^e
```

How can I write sub and superscripts in such an order shown in the above image?

Comment: Put braces around the whole thing:  `$\nabla_c {R_{abd}}^e$` typesets as $\nabla_c {R_{abd}}^e$.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: This is covered by point 5. of the dupe target.